# Serving an MJPEG stream with tornado in Python

Tags: python, tornado, mjpeg

I am trying to use the code here: http://pastie.org/7976455#165 with my own OpenCV routine to display an MJPG stream.

I setup the routing without a hitch

```
import threading
import time
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
import image_utils

class WebServer(threading.Thread):

def run(self):
    paths = [(r"/(.*)\.jpg", WebJPEGHandler),
        (r"/(.*)\.mjpg", WebMJPEGHandler)]
    web = tornado.web.Application(paths,debug=True)
    web.listen(listening_port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The JPEG code runs fine

```
class WebJPEGHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

@tornado.web.asynchronous
@gen.coroutine
def get(self, quality):
    image = image_utils.image_utils.getWebEncodedImage((detector.imageQ[-1]))
    self.set_header("Content-type", "image/jpg")
    self.write(str(image))
    yield gen.Task(self.flush)
```

but my own implementation (and I've tried a few variations) of the MJPG code results in a web page not available message from Chrome.

```
class WebMJPEGHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

@tornado.web.asynchronous
@gen.coroutine
def get(self, quality):
        loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
        self.served_image_timestamp = time.time()
        self.set_header( 'Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--boundarydonotcross')
        my_boundary = "--boundarydonotcross\n"
        while True:
            img = image_utils.image_utils.getWebEncodedImage((detector.imageQ[-1]))
            self.write(my_boundary)
            self.write("Content-type: image/jpg")
            self.write('Content-length: ' + str(len(img)))
            self.write(str(img))
            self.served_image_timestamp = time.time()
            print 'Image sent'
            time.sleep(0.5)
            yield gen.Task(self.flush)
```

It's probably some magic with boundaries and headers that I've missed but please help me to figure out what it is? Tornado itself doesn't give an error even in debug mode.

With some print statements I can see that it hits the loop between 2 and 4 times when I go to 127.0.0.1:5000/test.mjpg but then stops and nothing gets displayed.

Comment: I don't know anything about MJPEG, but one thing you're missing is newlines after the content-type and content-length inner headers (and probably a second newline between content-length and the content).

Comment: I tried your newlines suggestion - but didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Turns out it's chrome with the problem! Adding new lines in as Ben suggested made the code work in Firefox, but Chrome needs the whole stream as the source in an img tag for an MJPEG stream. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/PslmTeeM8Fo